# Delete lines that found in another file

Tags: php, file, text, replace, find

i have 2 files: 
`text1.txt` and `text2.txt`

how can i do this: if found a row in `text1.txt` that match to a row from `text2.txt`, delete it (or display the unique)?

this is what i have so far:

```
$a = file('text1.txt');
$b = file('text2.txt');
$contents = '';

foreach($b as $line2) {
    foreach($a as $line1) {
        if(!strstr($line1, $line2)) {
            $contents .= $line1; 
        }  
    }
}

file_put_contents('unique.txt', $contents);
```

Comment: Seems like you have the right idea, what output are you getting? Also, you may want to check out array_diff()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be:

```
file_put_contents('unique.txt', array_diff(file('text1.txt'), file('text2.txt')));
```

-since you're loading your files into RAM entirely, I suppose it's acceptable solution.

Also you may want to define your own function to determine if strings are equal. Logic then will be the same, but [array_udiff()](https://www.php.net/array_udiff) should be used

Comment: array_diff is to find unique value from 2 files, i want to check if the text from text.2 is found on text1 (primery), and if yes, so delete.

Comment: Hm. not sure I got that. Let me clarify: we have strings `'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'` in first file and be have string `'a', 'b'` in second. What do you want as result: `'c', 'b'` or just `'c'`?

Comment: just c, i have primary file and i have other file that i want to take all the lines from em, that have not found in the primary file

Comment: Then why it's not `array_diff()`? It will do exactly what you want - i.e. remove all entries that present in second file. See [this fiddle](http://3v4l.org/ut5P6): `array_diff()` will _not_ delete non-unique entries if the corresponding entry is absent in second array.